# How to make DataGridColumn ReadOnly but with CaretVisible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to have a DataGrid with a column in ReadOnly mode but with the Caret Visible? Similar to a Textbox when using the [IsReadOnlyCaretVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonlycaretvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) property?
If you set the IsReadOnly property the Column gets disabled and it is not possible to click on the cell.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Income}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can tinker with its template to achieve something but I'm not sure in this way. The only solution that comes to me now is to just avoid setting the `IsReadOnly` property and simply block any input (from keyboard and clipboard).

Comment: @EugenePodskal I have a custom Column that Inherits from DataGridTextColumn, and I don't set the IsReadOnly property of the column, and I set the IsReadOnly and IsReadOnlyCaretVisible of the inner textbox, however there are cases like when you are copying and pasting, or when you select the column and press a digit that succeed on changing the Content. I don't know what else to change or events I need to intercept to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Oh, I have been a bit inattentive while reading the question. In such a case you can try the template-based solution already posted as an answer.

Comment: @EugenePodskal yes, it was quite simple, I just need to rethink my custom column, to use Ganesh solution, though.

Comment: As I have already told you in the previous comment - "you can try the template-based solution already posted as an answer". And sorry for misleading you at first when I have skimmed over the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DataGridTemplateColumn with TextBox. refer below code.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                   
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Ah, I see, so instead of inheriting from DataGridTextColumn, I would need to inherit from DataGridTemplateColumn?